# iOS 11 simulator multitasking bar

Tags: ios, ios11, simulator

How to trigger the multitasking bar on iOS 11 simulator? I tried standard double

> Cmd + Shift + H

on both iPhone 8 and iPhone X simulators, but it doesn't seem to be working anymore.

**Edit:** tried few more times and apparently it still works, but like one try in ten. Does anyone experience the same behavior? Is it a simulator bug? Any idea how to improve it?

Comment: Same here, looks as a bug to me. As a workaround I keep pressing `Cmd + Shift + H` until the multitasking bar appears…

Comment: On MacBook Pro you can double tap the home button on the Touch Bar.

Comment: Same problem. Sometimes works, but most of time doesn't.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, and I see no difference if I go slow, go fast, or wait a bit. It appears to be completely random wether it works or not. And it does not work often...

Answer (score 0):

The standard Double (Apple + Shift + H) should work.